# Set wav file to filereference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, wav, filereference

I'm building a little recorder in flash and I have a little problem with sending the file that is recorded to php. Is there a way to simply send it with a var of do I need to set it to a file reference, but how can I do that because the only way I see that is that you need to browse or load is from somewhere.

Thanks
Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it to the server using this: [Save ByteArray to file with PHP](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2006/05/01/save-bytearray-to-file-with-php/)

Comment: You are my personal hero of the day! Thanks